# Fixed fields - question about a proposition from Dummit&Foote.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

This is from the 2nd statement of proposition $4$ from Dummit & Foote.

> [image]

It says the second is proved similarly, how so? If the argument is the same, doesn't it show $F_1 \subset F_2$

Because $H_1 = \{ \sigma(f_1) = f_1 \} \leq H_2 \leq Aut(K)$. So anything that is fixed in $H_1$ is fixed by $H_2$. Why do we also use field extension to denote subgroups?

Comment: You've got it the wrong way round. $H_1$ is contained in $H_2$, so everything fixed by $H_2$ is a fortiori fixed by $H_1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, what about the set $H_2 - H_1$?

Comment: Sorry, Hawk – what about it?

Comment: I mean there exists automoprhisms that would fix only $F_2$ and not $F_1$. So how would that include those elements?

Comment: If $\sigma$ is in $H_2$ but not in $H_1$, then $\sigma$ fixes everything in $F_2$, but not everything in $F_1$, so $F_2$ is contained in $F_1$, as Proposition 4 asserts.

Answer (score 1):

Given $x \in F_2$ then by definition $x$ is fixed by every element of $H_2$. Since $H_1 \subseteq H_2$, then $x$ is also fixed by every element of $H_1$, so $x \in F_1$.

Since $H_2$ is the larger subgroup, being fixed by every automorphism in $H_2$ is a *stronger* condition than being fixed by every automorphism in $H_1$. Correspondingly, the set of elements fixed by $H_2$ will be *smaller* than the set of elements fixed by $H_1$.

Comment: Sorry I am still confused. What about the elements $H_2 - H_1$, in $H_2$, but not $H_1$?

Comment: I've shown that every $x \in F_2$ is in $F_1$. What is your objection exactly? Elements of $H_2 - H_1$, if there are any, would fix every element of $F_2$, but need not fix all elements of $F_1$. In that case, $F_1$ would be strictly larger than $F_2$.

Comment: About your first statement that since $H_1 \subset H_2 \implies x \in F_1$. If we just take $H_2 = \{\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \}$ and $H_1 = \{\sigma_1\}$ with $\sigma(f_1) = f_1$, $\sigma_2(f_2) = f_2$, and $\sigma_1(f_2) \neq f_2$ necessarily.

Comment: If $f_2 \in F_2$, then it is fixed by every element of $H_2 = \{\sigma_1, \sigma_2\}$, so in particular $\sigma_1(f_2) = f_2$. Why do you think $\sigma_1(f_2) \neq f_2$? I see no justification for your assertion and indeed, it is wrong. If $f_1 \in F_1$, it could be the case that $\sigma_2(f_1) \neq f_1$, but that is no contradiction since $\sigma_2 \notin H_1$.

Comment: thanks, I think I am starting to see the picture. Initially I had a lot of trouble distinguishing $H_2$ from its fixed field $F_2$.

Comment: I think the inclusion comes from the fact that there is a possibility of $\sigma_1(f_2) = f_2$? And the fact that there might be a problem with $f_1 \in F_1$, but not necessarily $\sigma_2(f_1) = f_1$